# Three state value in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a global variable in excel vba named "State" which can be equal only to "high", "low" or "medium". Every time I want to call this variable, I have to make a check loop (using select case or if) to avoid having "state" equals to other values:

```
Select Case State
Case Is = "high"
'code
Case Is = "low"
'code
Case Is = "medium"
'code
Case Else
'error function
End Select
```

I wonder if there is a more sophisticated method that would make my variable more generic? I actually want to create a three state type (like the type boolean) which can be easily used for other functions

Comment: create [Enum Variable Type](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx)

Comment: if you search the VBA Object Browser for "true", you can find the VBA.[`VbTriState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177235.aspx) and the Office.[`MsoTriState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860737.aspx) `Enum`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `Enum`.  For example, define this at the top of your module:

```
Enum State
    High = 1
    Medium = 2
    Low = 3
End Enum
```

And you can make use of it, for example, like this:

```
Sub Test(testVal As State)
    Select Case testVal
        Case High
            MsgBox "High!!"
        Case Medium
            MsgBox "Medium!"
        Case Low
            MsgBox "Low."
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You might also want to add a fourth Enumeration `InvalidState = 0`, and of course, if your state is already in a string value, you'll need a function to convert the string into an enum...in which case you're kind of back where you started.

Comment: Should the Enum be declared inside the function or inside a public class?

Comment: @user3178129 -- Not inside the function -- inside the class (or module).